# Java JPA Hibernate OneToOne vs HashMap - Which One Should I Use and Why?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have a question about performance and common practice, if someone could explain this to me.

I have recently started using JPA and hibernate and have come across an Entity that has a foreign key and I need to get some data from it. So for example: CustomerAddress has a City and that city has a lot of detail and also a name.

SQL:

```
select 
  CA.Id, CI.Name  
from 
  CustomerAddress as CA 
    inner join City as CI
    on CA.CityID = CI.Id
```

So now in Java JPA Entity I can have a one-to-many annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerAddress")
public class CustomerAddressEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private City city;
  
}
```

Where City is also an @Entity with @Id and simple object.

Which in my opinion does not turn out the best because it makes a lot of SQL requests.

And then I have the option having just two findAll() calls at the beginning, where I would collect all the City Entities in a `HashMap<String, City>` and when needing the name I would just call `hashmap.get(key).getName()`.

EDIT (thanks for the heads up :)):
And when using this HashMap I can use a simpler Entity without the `@JoinColumn`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerAddress")
public class CustomerAddressEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CityID")
    private Long cityId;
  
}
```

In the hashmap case I only get two SQL calls and I think it works much faster. Is there a way to get this behavior also using JPA and hibernate?

If my question and code needs some more refinement please let me know.. I can edit the question with more details and perhaps if necessary provide a working example. Thank you for your thoughts :)

And the same would go for OneToMany, where the hashmap would be: `new HashMap<String, List<City>>` for example - I mean the whole example should be created a bit differently - I guess it could even be a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String,City>>` - if one would need quick access to the City by Id or sth... but i digress :) I will edit the question and respond to comments as I will go.. and refine the question if necessary.. I would just like to hear some thoughts and where my thinking is wrong :) and what am I failing to see and missing :)

EDIT: For example a code that would create a lot of SQL requests:

```
public interface CustomerAddressRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerAddressEntity, Long> {

    @Override
    List<CustomerAddressEntity> findAll();
}
```

This for example creates an SQL Query (I would use findAll() at the beginning to list all - or most of the Entities for the user) and you would get an SQL query for every Entity because it would want to find the Name of the City as well - because the ID of the City Entity does not really help to the user.

Also - I like to have all the Entities in my RAM so I can do a quick search for the user more responsive - So a search does not always do SQL Query + #(found results) Queries.

Comment: `because it makes a lot of SQL requests` ... what is the code which is making a lot of SQL requests?

Comment: just a simple findAll() from the JPArepository for example

Comment: If you build your own hash, you are on the hook to maintain it, and detect if/when there are changes. JPA caches (entity caching) can read from the DB and maintain what is in it's caches - giving you the same object reference, but refresh the data within it if/when required. It is why Identity is so fundamental in JPA when database tables don't really need it. I've built maps as you have from raw data if it is mostly small, static, and not likely to ever expand but go with entity caches for anything else. Your query performance is just due to how you fetch your existing model and easily fixed

Answer (score 1):

The HashMap has nothing to do with the fact that Hibernate issues a query when you want to get the name of the City object.Here's why it's happening.
In your CustomerAddressEntity you have a OneToOne with City , and since you have a @JoinColumn there ,it means that CustomerAddressEntity database Table will have the Primary Key of the City table as a foreign key , and since you specified in your class that it should be fetched LAZY,Hibernate will create a Proxy object wrapping the City object,ready to get queried from the database in case you call any getMethod ,like getName() ,(excluding the getId() method since the ID exists prealably in the proxy object,you can check the sql query logs and see that the query selects the foreign key with all the other fields of CustomerAddressEntity  ),that's why when you trigger the getName() method Hibernate will fetch that entity from the database.

Comment: It is kind of difficult to read your answer :) 

Both methods do the same - With HashMap I can avoid N * Select that Hibernate does because of the `@JoinColumn` - After I would use HashMap I would omit the `@JoinColumn` and just have a Long there or a String for the Id.. Maybe I can edit that as well in the question :)

Comment: @Jack Where are you gonna use the HashMap ? and what do you mean by omit the 
 JoinColumn ?

Comment: A user would like to have a list of all customers with city names - I could use HashMap with the String key - which is the CityId and I would provide him with that. Instead of doing SQL database queries I would have them in my HashMap that was loaded in the beginning and only once

Comment: @Jack It depends on your needs ,but using that includes that the HashMap will be always available in memory even when  not being used , you should prefer serving data when needed ,my opinion.

Comment: Could be - I guess if you would know that the data is not changed that often.. and that you would want to speed up the process.. the data of course could be stale.. I guess I would have to find a compromise between fresh data and responsiveness... because the SQL calls take some time, because the users are using slow connections with high pings...